# org-mode resize images with +/- but cannot save in the same location?

Tags: org-mode, inline-image

I have been trying to resize images in org-mode. It seems that I don't have imagemagick support, so I am trying to use +/-/o method. The problem is after I resize and press o, the prompt is to save at buffer location not image location!

Also, I have tried to open the image in image-buffer and tried to resize from there.
However, after I resize and save, the buffer get reverted immediately to the old dims!

What should I do?

Thank you

**EDIT**
To reproduce this:

1. Insert an inline image in org-mode

```
[[file:~/Desktop/image.jpg]]
```

2. Toggle inline image preview
3. With curser on image, run "image-decrease-size" and "image-increase-size", usually bound to + & -
4. After resizing image to desired dimension, run "image-save".

Problem: images is to be saved in the directory of the file and not in the original image directory.

Comment: I have no idea what you are describing: what does Org mode have to do with resizing images? I would suggest that you expand your question and add some details about what you are doing and what does not work.

Comment: @NickD I added more demo

Comment: Much better - thank you!